# Error inserting new column in ArcSDE table (ERROR 999999)

Tags: arcpy, sql-server, error-999999

I am using a python script to populate a table with values I get from rasters files. I use **arcpy.AddField_management** to add a new column and **arcpy.CalculateField_management** to insert the values for the new column. 
The table has more than 450 columns and after executing **arcpy.CalculateField_management** I get the following error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Underlying DBMS error [[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot create a row of size 8074 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.] 
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

I can avoid this error executing in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE REBUILD
```

Is there anyway to execute this SQL server instruction from the script or another equivalent way to avoid the error?